# How do i keep my hover effect active, when i clicked on the link?

Tags: php, sql, database

I im currently making an menu, for an album where I want to have an hover effect that stays on as soon as I clicked on one of the album links.

I already got the class in css, it's named " .active "

```
<?php

$query = "SELECT album_id, album_title FROM albums WHERE fk_category_id = 1";
$result = $mysqli->query($query);

while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $album_title = $row['album_title'];
    $album_id = $row['album_id'];

    echo "<a href='index.php?page=portfolio.php&album=$album_id'><p class='albums'>- $album_title</p></a>";

}

?>
```

Style:

```
nav ul li a:hover, nav ul li a.active {
    font-size: 20px !important;
    background-color: #2d2d2d;
    color: #b8df45;
}
```

I tried doing something like this, but it does not work.

```
if(isset($_GET['album'])){
    $album_number = $_GET['album'];

}

$query = "SELECT album_id, album_title FROM albums WHERE fk_category_id = 1";
$result = $mysqli->query($query);

while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $album_title = $row['album_title'];
    $album_id = $row['album_id'];

    $class = "";
    if ($album_number == $row['album_id']) {
        $class = "active";
    }

    echo "<a class='$class' href='index.php?page=portfolio.php&album=$album_id'><p class='albums'>- $album_title</p></a>";

}
```

Comment: Do you mean that on page load , the current link to current page should be active? or after page load you click on links and want to change color?

Comment: @AliSheikhpour I want it so as soon as you click on the link, there will be added an class .active to the link you clicked on, but only the one you currently clicked on, if i choose to click on another link it would be that one with the class .active

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify a class to you links and then a Jquery function to add class:

Adding class "link" to links:

```
<?php

$query = "SELECT album_id, album_title FROM albums WHERE fk_category_id = 1";
$result = $mysqli->query($query);

while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $album_title = $row['album_title'];
    $album_id = $row['album_id'];

    echo "<a class='links' href='index.php?page=portfolio.php&album=$album_id'><p class='albums'>- $album_title</p></a>";

}

?>
```

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".links").click(function(){
  $(this).addClass("active");
  });
});
```

You can also do this inline with your code but not recommended:

```
 echo "<a onclick='$(this).addClass(\"active\")' href='index.php?page=portfolio.php&album=$album_id'><p class='albums'>- $album_title</p></a>";
```

and this is without Jquery:

```
<a onclick="this.setAttribute("class", "active");">
```

Comment: It does not work, it seems like it add the active at the moment you click, but then resets right after. :(

Comment: Do you include jquery in your file?

Comment: I do it like this     <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>

Comment: please recheck  using CDN methods: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_get_started.asp

Comment: What is that for a script?

Comment: When you use jquery you have to include Jquery file into your project. You can download jquery or include it from CDN

Answer (score 0):

You can add a class or style to the link with javascript, when it is clicked, that gives it the proper style.

The styles are missings from your code, so I cannot work with that. But you could do something like:

```
echo "<a href='...' onclick=\"this.style='...';\">...</a>";
```

There are many other ways to do this in javascript, or with the help of JQuery.